# Is there an even number $a$ such that $a^{2^{n}}+1$ is prime for infinitely many $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, conjectures

Is there an even number $a$ such that $\{n: a^{2^{n}}+1 \text{ is prime} \}$ is an infinite set?

Let $a$ be even. Is there infinitely many $n$ such that $a^{2^{n}}+1$ is composite?

Comment: IIRC these are called Generalized Fermat numbers and primality and compositeness are open.

Comment: Could you give us some references if you have read in somewhere？ Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check e.g. https://oeis.org/wiki/Generalized_Fermat_numbers

Comment: If $a$ is of the form $b^c$ with $c\ge3$ odd, then $a^{2^n}+1$ is composite for all $n$. It's $r^c+1$ for $r=b^{2^n}$, so it's divisible by $r+1$.

Answer (score 12):

A remark that might be noteworthy...

- Either the sequence $\{2^{2^{n}}+1\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ contains
  infinitely many composite numbers or the sequence $\{6^{2^{n}}+1\}_{n
  \in \mathbb{N}}$ contains infinitely many composite numbers.

*Proof.* If there are only finitely many composite numbers in the first sequence (the sequence of Fermat numbers), we might assure the existence of an $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{2^{n}}+1$ is a prime number for every $n$ that belongs to $\mathcal{I}:=[n_{0},\infty) \cap \mathbb{N}$.

We claim that, in such a case, $6^{2^{n}}+1$ is a composite number for every $n \in \mathcal{I}$. Indeed,  for any given $n \in \mathcal{I}$, the Fermat number $2^{2^{n}}+1$ is a prime and [Pepin's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9pin%27s_test) gives us that
$$3^{2^{n-1}} \equiv -1 \pmod{2^{2^{n}}+1}.$$
Taking squares on both sides of the previous congruence we get
$3^{2^{n}} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{2^{n}}+1}$; from this information and the fact that $2^{2^{n}} \equiv -1 \pmod{2^{2^{n}}+1}$, we obtain  that $$6^{2^{n}} \equiv -1 \pmod{2^{2^{n}}+1}$$ and the validity of our claim follows.